# some functions are not working as intended

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I'm developing a cash register program with Netbeans. And it was working well when I used it with Eclipse. However, after I changed some GUI by using Netbeans, the functions are not working. (Payment, Cancel)
And I don't know why -order- comes out when I hit the New Order button.
What's wrong with my code? Please!

```
package point.of.sales;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    void initializeBill()
    {
        nTotal = 0;
        txtBill.setText(spaces(35) + "- Order -" );
        btnTomatoBasilLinguine.setEnabled(true);
        btnLinguineCarbonara.setEnabled(true);
        btnShrimpPasta.setEnabled(true);
        btnGrilledSalmonSalad.setEnabled(true);
        btnCapreseSalad.setEnabled(true);
        btnCoke.setEnabled(true);
        btnGingerale.setEnabled(true);
    }
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel5 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jTabbedPane1 = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
        jPanel7 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        btnCheeseSalad = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnGrilledSalmonSalad = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnCapreseSalad = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        btnNewOrder = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnCancel = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnPayment = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        txtBill = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jPanel8 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        btnShrimpPasta = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnTomatoBasilLinguine = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnLinguineCarbonara = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jPanel9 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        btnBeer = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnCoke = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnGingerale = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());



        btnGrilledSalmonSalad.setText("Grilled Salmon Salad");
        btnGrilledSalmonSalad.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnGrilledSalmonSaladActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnCapreseSalad.setText("Caprese Salad");
        btnCapreseSalad.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnCapreseSaladActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                    .addComponent(btnCheeseSalad, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(btnGrilledSalmonSalad, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 167, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(btnCapreseSalad, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 168, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(btnGrilledSalmonSalad, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 43, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(btnCapreseSalad, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 43, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(btnCheeseSalad, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 43, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(40, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        jPanel2.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

        btnNewOrder.setText("New Order");
        btnNewOrder.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnNewOrderActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnCancel.setText("Cancel");

        btnPayment.setText("Payment");

        txtBill.setColumns(20);
        txtBill.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(txtBill);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(btnNewOrder, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 97, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(btnPayment, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 111, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(btnCancel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 99, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(39, 39, 39))
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 353, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 362, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(btnNewOrder, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 39, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(btnCancel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 39, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(btnPayment, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 39, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        jTextField1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.CENTER);
        jTextField1.setText("Tasting Room");
        jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jPanel8.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

        btnShrimpPasta.setText("Shrimp Pasta");
        btnShrimpPasta.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnShrimpPastaActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnTomatoBasilLinguine.setText("Tomato Basil Linguine");
        btnTomatoBasilLinguine.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnTomatoBasilLinguineActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnLinguineCarbonara.setText("Linguine Carbonara");
        btnLinguineCarbonara.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnLinguineCarbonaraActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel8Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel8);
        jPanel8.setLayout(jPanel8Layout);
        jPanel8Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel8Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel8Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel8Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                    .addComponent(btnShrimpPasta, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(btnTomatoBasilLinguine, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 167, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(btnLinguineCarbonara, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 168, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel8Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel8Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel8Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel8Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(btnTomatoBasilLinguine, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 43, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(btnLinguineCarbonara, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 43, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(btnShrimpPasta, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 43, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(40, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        jPanel9.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

        btnBeer.setText("Beer");
        btnBeer.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnBeerActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnCoke.setText("Coke ");
        btnCoke.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnCokeActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnGingerale.setText("Ginger Ale");
        btnGingerale.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnGingeraleActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel9Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel9);
        jPanel9.setLayout(jPanel9Layout);
        jPanel9Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel9Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel9Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel9Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                    .addComponent(btnBeer, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(btnCoke, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 167, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(btnGingerale, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 168, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel9Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel9Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel9Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel9Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(btnCoke, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 43, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(btnGingerale, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 43, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(btnBeer, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 43, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(40, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel7Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel7);
        jPanel7.setLayout(jPanel7Layout);
        jPanel7Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel7Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel7Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel7Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 351, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jPanel8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 351, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jPanel9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 351, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 360, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap())
            .addGroup(jPanel7Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(153, 153, 153)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 461, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel7Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel7Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel7Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(6, 6, 6)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 42, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel7Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addGroup(jPanel7Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jPanel8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jPanel9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
        );

        jTabbedPane1.addTab("Cash Register", jPanel7);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel5Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel5);
        jPanel5.setLayout(jPanel5Layout);
        jPanel5Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel5Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jTabbedPane1)
        );
        jPanel5Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel5Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jTabbedPane1)
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        
    private void addItem(String food, double price)
    {
        txtBill.setText(txtBill.getText()+"\n"+" "+food+PRICE_FORMAT.format(price)+"\n");
        nPreviousPrice = price;
        nTotal +=price;
    }

    String spaces(int num)
    {
        String str="";
        for(int i=0; i<num; i++)
            str+=" ";
        return str;
    }

    double getAmout()
    {
        try {
                String strAnswer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                        "Please enter the amout paid: ",
                        "Amout Paid", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
                return Double.parseDouble(strAnswer);}
       catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter a number.",
                    "Number Format Exception", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
            return -1;
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Transaction Canceled");
            return -2;
        }
    }

    double getAmount()
    {
        try {
                String strAnswer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
                    "Please enter the amount paid: ",
                    "Amount Paid", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
                return Double.parseDouble(strAnswer);
            }
        catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter a number.",
                    "Number Format Exception", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
            return -1;
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Transaction Canceled");
            return -2;
        }
    }

    private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void btnTomatoBasilLinguineActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                       
       addItem("Tomato Basil Linguine" + spaces(19),13);
       btnPayment.setEnabled(true);
       btnCancel.setEnabled(true);// TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                                      

    private void btnCokeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
       addItem("Coke" + spaces(52), 2);
       btnPayment.setEnabled(true);
       btnCancel.setEnabled(true);
       repaint(); // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                       

    private void btnCapreseSaladActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
            addItem("Caprese Salad" + spaces(33), 5);
            btnPayment.setEnabled(true);
            btnCancel.setEnabled(true);
            repaint();    // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                               

    private void btnGingeraleActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
            addItem("Gingerale" + spaces(44), 2);
            btnPayment.setEnabled(true);
            btnCancel.setEnabled(true);
            repaint();       // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                            

    private void btnBeerActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
            addItem("Beer" + spaces(53),3);
            btnPayment.setEnabled(true);
            btnCancel.setEnabled(true);
            repaint();// TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                       



    private void btnNewOrderActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
            initializeBill();
            repaint();// TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void btnLinguineCarbonaraActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                     
            addItem("Linguine Carbonara" + spaces(24),15);
            btnPayment.setEnabled(true);
            btnCancel.setEnabled(true);
            repaint();    // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                                    

    private void btnShrimpPastaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
            addItem("Shrimp Pasta" + spaces(35),14);
            btnPayment.setEnabled(true);
            btnCancel.setEnabled(true);
            repaint();// TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                              


    private void btnCalculateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
            nSubTotal = nTotal;

            txtBill.setText(txtBill.getText() + "\n" +
                "     " + "Total: " + spaces(41) + PRICE_FORMAT.format(nTotal) + "\n");

            btnPayment.setEnabled(false);
            btnCancel.setEnabled(false);
            btnTomatoBasilLinguine.setEnabled(false);
            btnLinguineCarbonara.setEnabled(false);
            btnShrimpPasta.setEnabled(false);
            btnCoke.setEnabled(false);
            btnGingerale.setEnabled(false);

            // get amount paid by client
            double nAnswer = getAmount();

            // if the cancel button is pressed, reinitialize.
            if (nAnswer == DIALOG_CANCEL)
                initializeBill();
            else
            {
                // while the client gives an insufficent amount, ask again
                while (nAnswer < nSubTotal)
                {
                    if (nAnswer != DIALOG_NOT_NUM)
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                            "The amount paid must be at least " + 
                            PRICE_FORMAT.format(nSubTotal),
                            "Insufficent Amount", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
                    nAnswer = getAmount();
                    if (nAnswer == DIALOG_CANCEL)
                    {
                        initializeBill();
                        return;
                    }
                }

                txtBill.setText(txtBill.getText() + "\n" +
                    "     " + "Paid: " + spaces(42) + 
                    PRICE_FORMAT.format(nAnswer));
                txtBill.setText(txtBill.getText() + "\n" +
                    "     " + "Returned: " + spaces(33) + 
                    PRICE_FORMAT.format(nAnswer-nSubTotal));
            }
            repaint();
        }        

    private void btnCancelActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
txtBill.setText(txtBill.getText() + "\n" +
               "     " + strPreviousDrink + 
            spaces(40 - strPreviousDrink.length()) + "-" +
            PRICE_FORMAT.format(nPreviousPrice) + "\n" +  "     (Canceled)\n");
            nTotal -= nPreviousPrice;
            btnCancel.setEnabled(false);
            repaint();
        }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    private final DecimalFormat PRICE_FORMAT = new DecimalFormat("$###.##");

    // flag, if the user does not enter a number in the dialog
    private final int DIALOG_NOT_NUM = -1;                            

    // flag, if the user cancels the dialog
    private final int DIALOG_CANCEL = -2;    
    private double nTotal = 0, nSubTotal = 0, nPreviousPrice = 0;
    private String strPreviousDrink;
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton btnBeer, btnCancel, btnCapreseSalad, btnCheeseSalad, btnCoke, btnGingerale, btnGrilledSalmonSalad, btnLinguineCarbonara, btnNewOrder, btnPayment, btnShrimpPasta, btnTomatoBasilLinguine;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1, jPanel2, jPanel5, jPanel7, jPanel8, jPanel9;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTabbedPane jTabbedPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea txtBill;      
}
```

Comment: I had to shorten my post because of the character limit. let me know if you need more information.

Comment: 1. For help sooner, please post an [mcve]. 2. I recommend against using a GUI builder (which your code and post suggests) 3. Its not evident where ActionListener's are added to those JButtons

Comment: As commented by @copeg we don't need your whole code, but instead make a new project, a simpler one and try to reproduce your problem, then post that code here. And also, it's better if you do the coding yourself instead of using the GUI builder (drag & drop), because it will make a spaghetti code which is really hard to read and understand

Comment: oh, thanks for the advice! I though that lots of people were using this program and it was the useful tool to use. :) I'll try to do it by myself even though it's small stuffs.

Answer (score 3):

> However, after I changed some GUI by using Netbeans, the functions are not working. (Payment, Cancel

You must add an `ActionListener` implementation to a `JButton` in order to handle the action accordingly. This seems to be missing for both your `btnCancel` and `btnPayment`. For instance:

```
btnCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        btnCancelActionPerformed(e);
    }
});
```

If you are using a GUI builder, I recommend against it: code can be hard to read, easy to break, and if/when it does break not knowing the basics of how/why the code was constructed makes bugs very difficult to diagnose.

Comment: Okay  I'll stay away from the GUI builder!